# HTTP POST Request from ionic 3 - PayFort Integration (Redirect Mode)

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework, payfort

I'm attempting to integrate PayFort to an ionic app.
No SDK available for ionic so I'm integrating Redirect Mode where we just open a Webpage from Supplier.

Using HttpClient on ionic

```
let data = JSON.stringify({
  'access_code' : 'xxxxxxxx',
  'amount' : '10000',
  'command' : 'AUTHORIZATION',
  'currency' : 'SAR',
  'customer_email' : 'test@payfort.com',
  'language' : 'en',
  'merchant_identifier' : 'xxxxxxxx',
  'merchant_reference' : 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx',
  'payment_option' : 'MASTERCARD',
  'signature' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' });


return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
this.http
.post(apiUrl,data,options)
.subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log("Success: ",data);
    resolve(data);
  },
  error=>{
    console.log("Error:",error);
    reject(error);
  }
);
})
```

After executing this code, PayFort returns with 'Parameters Missing' Error.

Same params work on PHP & HTML.

Also tried the following formats of params

```
let dataString = 'access_code=xxxxxxxxxxx&amount=10000&command=AUTHORIZATION&currency=SAR&customer_email=test@payfort.com&language=en&merchant_identifier=xxxxxxx&merchant_reference=xxxxxxxxxx&payment_option=MASTERCARD&signature=xxxxxxxx'

let dataStringInJSON = {'access_code=xxxxxxxxxxx&amount=10000&command=AUTHORIZATION&currency=SAR&customer_email=test@payfort.com&language=en&merchant_identifier=xxxxxxx&merchant_reference=xxxxxxxxxx&payment_option=MASTERCARD&signature=xxxxxxxx'}


let dataJSON = {
  'access_code' : 'xxxxxxxx',
  'amount' : '10000',
  'command' : 'AUTHORIZATION',
  'currency' : 'SAR',
  'customer_email' : 'test@payfort.com',
  'language' : 'en',
  'merchant_identifier' : 'xxxxxxxx',
  'merchant_reference' : 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx',
  'payment_option' : 'MASTERCARD',
  'signature' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }
```

Comment: Hi , i am also using ionic 3 with payfort reirection mode. in browser event url i am recieving fort id. But i dont know how to get all details . Can you please guide me how you did this integration with payfort. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try to send JSON object instead of JSON string.

```
let data = Your JSON object
```

Comment: As mentioned in the last part of question, it has already been tried. Take a look at 

'let dataJSON  = { ......'

Comment: You can try this link: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/payfort-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/payfort-node)